# Chovos Halevavos' Proof from Design

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, proof-of-torah

Where (preferably online) is the passage of Rabbeinu Bahya Ibn Paqud in his Chovos Halevavos (in Shaar HaYichud I believe) in which he proves the existence of the Creator by citing a story where a comparison is made to the ability to detect non-randomness in a well written poem (i.e. that it was not created accidentally by spilt ink)?

Comment: If one of the answer is acceptable to you, consider marking it accepted. Kol Tuv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shaar yichud ch.7 [online](http://dafyomireview.com/398)

> The analogy of this: When one sees a letter of uniform handwriting and
>   writing style, one will immediately consider that one person wrote it
>   because it is not possible that there was not at least one person. If
>   it were possible that it could have been written with less than one
>   person, we would consider this possibility. And even though it is
>   possible that it was written by more than one person, it is not proper
>   to consider this, unless there is evidence which testifies to this,
>   such as different handwriting style in part of the letter or the like.
>
> Since this is so, it is not necessary to know Him face to face, if
>   this is not possible, and it will suffice for us to see the letter,
>   accepting as proof the writer's acts, namely, the form of the writing,
>   instead of seeing the writer himself. From this alone, we will know
>   clearly that one writer exists, who knows how to write and is capable
>   of writing, and that he wrote this letter, and did not partner with
>   someone else in writing it. This we can see from its orderly form and
>   uniform handwriting, since the handiwork of two makers is changing, it
>   is not uniform and orderly in one unison, and it changes in quality
>   and character.
>
> Similarly we will say regarding the Creator, since the signs of wisdom
>   in His creations are similar and uniform, we must conclude that one
>   Creator created them, because the existence of the created things is
>   impossible without Him.

also in ch.6

> There are some people who claim that the world came into being by
>   chance, without a Creator who created it and without a Maker who
>   formed it. It is amazing to me how a rational, healthy human being
>   could entertain such a notion. If such a person heard someone else
>   saying the same thing about a water wheel, which turns to irrigate
>   part of a field or a garden, saying that it came to be without a
>   craftsman who designed it and toiled to assemble it and placed each
>   part for a beneficial purpose - he would be greatly amazed on him,
>   consider him a complete fool, and be swift to call him a liar and
>   reject his words. And since he would reject such a notion for a mere
>   simple, insignificant water wheel, which was made through basic design
>   for rectifying a small piece of land - how could he allow himself to
>   entertain such a notion for the entire universe which surrounds the
>   earth and everything in it, and which is designed with a wisdom that
>   no rational human intellect is capable of fathoming, and which is
>   prepared for the benefit of the earth and everything on it. How could
>   he claim that it came to be without purposeful intent and thought of a
>   capable wise Being?
>
> It is evident to us that for things which come about without the
>   intent of an intender (i.e. an intelligence who designed it with a
>   purpose) - none of them will display any trace of wisdom or ability.
>   Behold and see, that if a man suddenly pours ink on clean paper, it
>   would be impossible for there to be drawn on it orderly writing and
>   legible lines like it would be with a quill, and if a man brought
>   before us orderly writing from what cannot be written without use of a
>   quill, and he would say that ink was spilled on paper, and the form of
>   the writing happened on its own, we would be quick to call him a liar
>   to his face and tell him that it must have been written with an
>   intelligent person's intent

(BTW, nobody has ever refuted this premise. the evidence for evolution is for things like common ancestry but nobody has ever observed a functional complex structure arising from unguided natural processes.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22270/discussion-on-answer-by-ray-chovos-halevavos-proof-from-design).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.simpletoremember.com/articles/a/the-design-argument/) website, Rabbenu Bachya makes  this argument in “The Duties of the Heart,” The Gate of Oneness, Chapter 6:

> Do you not realize that if ink were poured out accidentally on a blank
>   sheet of paper, it would be impossible that proper writing should
>   result, legible lines that are written with a pen? Imagine a person
>   bringing a sheet of handwriting that could only have been composed
>   with a pen. He claims that ink spilled on the paper and these written
>   characters had accidentally emerged. We would charge him to his face
>   with falsehood, for we could feel certain that this result could not
>   have happened without an intelligent person’s purpose.
>
> Since this seems impossible in the case of letters whose formation
>   is conventional, how can one assert that something far subtler in its
>   design and which manifests in its fashioning a depth and complexity
>   infinitely beyond our comprehension could have happened without the
>   purpose, power, and wisdom of a wise and mighty designer? (“The Duties
>   of the Heart,” The Gate of Oneness, Chapter 6)

If you don't believe this quote is authentic, you can also see this quote in Rabbi Bleich's [With Perfect Faith](https://books.google.com/books?id=OKL4bGl-S80C&lpg=PA85&ots=LidwD2niIC&dq=Do%20you%20not%20realize%20that%20if%20ink%20were%20poured%20out%20accidentally%20on%20a%20blank%20sheet%20of%20paper%2C%20it%20would%20be%20impossible%20that%20proper%20writing%20should%20result%2C%20legible%20lines%20that%20are%20written%20with%20a%20pen%3F&pg=PA85#v=onepage&q=Do%20you%20not%20realize%20that%20if%20ink%20were%20poured%20out%20accidentally%20on%20a%20blank%20sheet%20of%20paper,%20it%20would%20be%20impossible%20that%20proper%20writing%20should%20result,%20legible%20lines%20that%20are%20written%20with%20a%20pen?&f=false), which has a Google preview, and [The Duties of the Heart](https://books.google.com/books?id=ITFaAAAAYAAJ&q=you%20not%20realize%20that%20if%20ink%20were%20poured%20out%20accidentally%20on%20a%20blank%20sheet%20of%20paper,%20it%20would%20be%20impossible%20that%20proper%20writing%20should%20result,%20legible%20lines%20that%20are%20written%20with%20a%20pen&dq=you%20not%20realize%20that%20if%20ink%20were%20poured%20out%20accidentally%20on%20a%20blank%20sheet%20of%20paper,%20it%20would%20be%20impossible%20that%20proper%20writing%20should%20result,%20legible%20lines%20that%20are%20written%20with%20a%20pen&hl=en&sa=X&ei=I4YQVdLHFsqsyATe9oGgCA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw) itself (which only has snippet view).

Comment: isnt this the same quote as the other answer?