# Midrashic(?) Proof from Design story about overturned inkwell

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, midrash, agada-stories-legends, proof-of-torah

I believe I read years ago about an instance where a rabbi presented a heretic with a well written poem that he claimed had actually formed accidentally when he overturned his inkwell. I though I had seen it in the Shaar HaYichud of the Chovos Helevavos though [it seems that may just be a very similar proof but without the actual anecdote](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56713/chovos-halevavos-proof-from-design/56714#56714). Is there such an account/medrash in the Jewish/Rabbinic literature (perhaps cited in a footnote on a version of the Chovos Halevavos) or did my memory make it up randomly out of whole cloth?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56713/chovos-halevavos-proof-from-design#comment150936_56714

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56717/1012), the Chovos Halevavos makes the argument from overturned ink. However, there is a Midrashic precedent for your recollection as well, cited [here](http://www.urbantraditional.com/urban/an_essay_on_faith.php):

> We see this in the Midrash (Midrash Temurah in Midrash Aggadot
>   Bereshit):
>
> An athiest [sic] came to Rebbi Akiva. "Who created the world?", he queried.
>   R. Akiva answered, "The Holy One, blessed be He." The athiest [sic] replied,
>   "Show me proof." R. Akiva said, "Come back to me tomorrow and I shall
>   prove it to you."
>
> When the man returned the following day, R. Akiva began by asking,
>   "What is that you are wearing?" "A piece of clothing," the athiest [sic]
>   replied."And who made it?" R. Akiva continued. "The weaver", he
>   replied. "Show me proof", R. Akiva demanded. "But how can I show you
>   proof if it isn't already obvious to you that it is the work of the
>   weaver?!"
>
> With this R. Akiva said, "Have you not heard what your own lips have
>   spoken? Isn't it obvious to you that the Holy One has created this
>   world? Doesn't the clothing testify to the weaver; the house and the
>   door to a builder and a carpenter? Just so does the world testity to
>   the One who made it."

The Hebrew original of this Midrash appears [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31255&st=&pgnum=25&hilite=) [אוצר המדרשים (אייזנשטיין) תמורה עמוד 583, בתי מדרשות ח"ב מדרש תמורה השלם פרק ה]:

> ומעשה שבא מין ואמר לר' עקיבא העוה"ז מי בראו א"ל הקב"ה, א"ל הראיני דבר
>   ברור, א"ל למחר תבא אלי, למחר בא אצלו א"ל מה אתה לובש, א"ל בגד, א"ל מי
>   עשאו, א"ל האורג, א"ל איני מאמינך הראיני דבר ברור, א"ל ומה אראה לך ואין
>   אתה יודע שהאורג עשאו, א"ל ואתה אינך יודע שהקב"ה ברא את עולמו, נפטר
>   אותו המין, אמרו לו תלמידיו מה הדבר ברור, א"ל בניי כשם שהבית מודיע על
>   הבנאי והבגד מודיע על האורג והדלת על הנגר, כך העולם מודיע על הקב"ה שהוא
>   בראו, ישתבח ויתעלה שמו לעד ולנצח נצחים, אמן ואמן נצח סלה ועד.

Comment: hattip @ray who found what seems like the medrash as quoted from the end of the chovos halevavos perek 6 as I remembered - from R.A. Kaplan who perhaps also misquoted from memory (?) with regard to spilt ink and Rabbi Meir (instead of Rabbi Akiva): A philosopher once came to Rabbi Meir and told him, "I don't believe in God. I feel that the universe came into being by itself, of its own accord, without any outside help." ... A few days later, he came to the philosopher, and showed him a beautiful piece...http://ou.org.s3.amazonaws.com/publications/kaplan/infinitelight/1.htm#6

Comment: (Alternatively, there is an additional/alternate version of the medrash possibly cited in a version of the chovos halevavos that noone's dug up yet online...?)

Comment: @loewian I doubt it

Comment: It looks like R. Kaplan's version is combination of Chovos Halevavos and the above Midrash, which does not actually appear in the Chovos Halevavos, despite R. Kaplan's footnote.